# Add Debug script into Stored Procedures

Tags: sql

If you’re writing dynamic SQL, always add a Debug mode. It doesn’t have to be anything fancy at first, just something like:

```
IF @Debug = 1 BEGIN PRINT @MySQLInjectionGift END;
```

How can we use the above script in our Stored procedure

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and the features and syntax for stored procedures are completely vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 0):

It can be used as a parameter to inject code.

```
DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.usp_myproc
GO
CREATE PROC dbo.usp_myproc  (@Debug bit = 0)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MySQLInjectionGift varchar(max) ='a=''HI THERE'','

    DECLARE @SQL varchar(max) = 
    '
    SELECT TOP 3'+IIF(@Debug=1,@MySQLInjectionGift,'')+'* FROM SYS.TABLES
    '

    EXEC (@SQL)
END

GO
EXEC usp_myproc 
GO
EXEC usp_myproc @Debug = 1
```

You can do anything with it like create WHERE clauses on the fly, create columns that do calculations that are not part of the actual query but helpful in debugging.  Typical injection include arbitrary SQL select statements that show progress from one SQL to another as when the stored procedure is large, the decision execution path may not be clear especially when there are lots of conditional statement.  The debug mode can also run start-up code that can prepare the data or execute a unit test at the end of the query.